# How to find out if an object is an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor, type-conversion

While going through javascript tutorial on 'W3Schools', I found this bit of code explaining how to to find out if an object is an Array.

```
function isArray(myArray) {
    return myArray.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") > -1;
}
```

I am not understanding how does that particular line executes.

[Link to W3School's page in question](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: What have you tried ? Maybe start by decomposing the function see what each method or attribute contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this question has accepted answer about a right way of using `Array.isArray()`

Question was about executing particular code from W3Schools, so for educational reasons there is what is happening in code example.

`myArray.constructor` is reference to object constructor. More at [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

With that in mind, we can proceed to:

```
myArray.constructor.toString()
```

Will result into

> function Array() {
>       [native code] }

Function `indexOf` will return position of string sequence in other string sequence. If string we are looking for is found it will return `int` position. If not `indexOf` will return -1.

Function could be described as If position of "Array" in stringified contructor of object is greater then -1, object is array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What are the asterix-characters `*` doing?

Comment: There are no `*` characters on W3Schools example. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) I think it's either syntax i dont know about or attempt to style text in question.

Comment: Edited the question, asterix' removed.

Comment: The W3Schools rightly explains that `Array.isArray()` is not supported in older browsers (IE < 9). The code in question works for these older browsers as well.